# Is active dry yeast safe to eat as-is?

Tags: yeast

I am interested in eating yeast as a protein supplement, likely on toast.

Is active dry yeast safe to eat in this way?

Comment: Jeremy, welcome to Seasoned Advice! There are two hints: a) We don't accept questions on health and nutrition (please see our [help] for more details. b) Please read about the difference between *[Candida albicans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candida_albicans)* and *[Saccharomyces cervisiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_yeast)*.

Comment: That’s like saying, “I’m thinking about eating yogurt but worried I’ll get a bacterial infection”

Comment: Look for Vegemite or Marmite. It is autolyzed (dead) yeast that is used as a spread on bread in many parts of the world. It’s likely a lot tastier than baking yeast.

Comment: No, but you might end up fluffy, bubbly, double the initial size, and get punched down.

Comment: I've edited to try to avoid this being a health question - I removed the specific concern, and simply asked if it's safe to eat active dry yeast, which should be an answerable yes/no question. People are also providing answers about *other* kinds of yeast that are better to eat. I'm not sure whether you're interested in that or not?

Comment: A quick check online suggests it's [not far short of 50% protein](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/sainsburys-bread-yeast--fast-action--dried-56g) but how much do you reckon you can get on a slice of toast? Brown bread has about 3g/slice to start with and more than about 1--2g of yeast on that would be like eating dust.  Though it is a very cheap source of protein per gram

Comment: Not about health. You would need really a lot of yeast. Brewer yeast is a common supplement but I guess for some vitamins (forgot which one (s) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use yeast as an ingredient for umami and protein content, said spreads (any-mite) or so-called "nutritional yeast flakes" are the most palatable yet yeast-rich options.